# I am getting confused about how do i write a switch case instead of the if condition using javaScript only

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, html-table, crud

here is my validation function which I wanted to define using the switch case but I'm confused about how to fit this particular code in the switch case.

```
 function validation() {
    var formrdvalid = false;
    var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    var city =  document.getElementById("city");
    var radios = document.getElementsByName("gender");
    var agree = document.getElementById("invalidCheck").checked;

    if (fname == "") {
        alert("please enter firstname");
    }

    if (city.selectedIndex === 0) {
        alert("select the city");
        return false;
    }
    if (!formrdvalid) {
      for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
        if (radios[i].checked) {
        formrdvalid = true;
        }
      }
    }

    if (!formrdvalid) {
      alert( "please select gender");
      return false;
    }

    if(agree === false){
        alert("agree terms and conditions");
    }

    if (!fname||!city || !radios || !agree ) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: A switch block is not suitable to replace multiple ifs that all deal with different variables. A switch block makes it easier to test a *single variable* against multiple values.

Comment: unsure how a switch would make any sense here. Switch is meant for matching defined values, you do not have anything like that in your code.  The code can be cleaned up a lot, but using a switch in that clean up is not the correct approach.

Comment: yess i do know that using a switch case doesn't make any sense here but my senior wants me to do that just to learn how to apply the switch case at this situation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think it's possible. And sometimes (maybe not in your case) it's really useful.

To do so, you should declare a variable that represent whole state of form, like this:

```js
var formrdvalid = false;
var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
var city =  document.getElementById("city");
var radios = document.getElementsByName("gender");
var agree = document.getElementById("invalidCheck").checked;

// this represents state of the form, including all important info
// like a table
var state = `${formrdvalid}|${fname}|${city}|${radios}|${agree}`;

// now you should just list all valid states
switch(state) {
case `true|myform|London|22|true`:
case VALID_STATE2:
case VALID_STATE3:
  return true;
default:
  return false;
}
```

Sometimes it is more convenient to define invalid cases and return `true` by default.

Comment: Those valid states are probably in the thousands... this is not a good answer. Using switch here is nonsense in the first place.

Comment: Yes, it's userful only when every variable is discrete and has very few possible states. But I don't know, maybe, e.g if `city` variable can be either `London` or `Paris` then this trick can make sense.

Comment: If there's five values where each has two possible states you already have 32 strings to list. On a spectrum from feasible to nonsense, using switch here is at the very end of the nonsense side. You literally cannot make it more cumbersome.